# How to get smooth edges in grabcut in Emgu c#

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I have done the grabcut implementation interactive in c# but there is one problem which Iam unable to solve. How to smooth the edges. The edges looks rough after applying grabcut. I googled and found out a solution in c++ but I am unable to convert it into c#. Here What I have done so far.

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> image = new Image<Bgr, Byte>("SourceImage");  
Image<Gray, Byte> mask1 = newMask;//Grabcut mask
Image<Bgr, float> maskF = mask1.Convert<Bgr, float>();
Image<Bgr, float> maskF2 = maskF.Mul(1 / 255);
Image<Bgr, float> imageF = image.Convert<Bgr, float>();
var img= imageF.Mul(maskF).Convert<Bgr, byte>();
Image<Bgr, byte> result3 = new Image<Bgr, byte>(imageSource.Width, imageSource.Height);
imageSource.Copy(result3, newMask);Pictureboxoutput.image=(result3+img).ToBitMap();
```

[OutputImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngOQY.jpg)[InputImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNkFc.jpg)

Comment: why don't you post images of the source image and the mask you are receiving that visualize your issue?

Comment: @slawekwin I have uploaded the images.

Comment: did you try applying [GaussianBlur](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.0/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=gaussianblur#gaussianblur) on the original image or [opening/closing](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html) resulting mask to clear some noise?

Comment: @slawekwin yes I applied the smoothGaussian Method on newMask but its it not making the edges smooth.

Comment: You are supposed to blur the input image (before mask extraction). When you already have the mask, you could try to smooth it with some morphological operations (see link in my previous comment)

Comment: @slawekwin Thanks for the response but it would be more helpful if you can help me with C# emgu.